# Relationship between LinearModel & GeneralizedLinearMixedModel classes

Tags: matlab, oop, time-series, linear-regression, superclass

Matlab defines `LinearModel` and `GeneralizedLinearMixedModel` classes. Browsing the documentation indicates that either (i) one is derived from the other, or (ii) there is automatic conversion. These are complex objects, and I am just starting to explore them, so I apologize if their relationship is obvious, but what exactly is their relationship?

Note also that I expressed (i) and (ii) above in terms of my object-oriented background (C++), and I know there maybe be differences with the Matlab paradigm.

This question arose because the function `coefTest` accepts a `GeneralizedLinearMixedModel` object, yet the Econometrics toolbox example ["Time Series Regression IX: Lag Order Selection"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-ix-lag-order-selection.html) submits a `LinearModel` object instead.

Note that this this question pertains to Matlab-specific classes and the Matlab command `coefTest`. As such, it does not belong on "Cross Validated" Stack Exchange forum. I posted this to:

[Relationship between LinearModel & GeneralizedLinearMixedModel classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491094/relationship-between-linearmodel-generalizedlinearmixedmodel-classes)

http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/OHLajBEuPU0

Comment: If your actual problem is that you can't get the Econometrics toolbox example to run, you should note that the online documentation only pertains to the current `version` of Matlab (R2015a as of now). If you're using an older version, you should look search for this example (or a similar one) in the built-in documentation (`doc`).

Comment: I'm using 2014b and also reading the that version's documentation.  I have yet to run tutorial code that does not work.  However, here, I'm just trying to follow the example, which  means that as I invoke help on the commands, I need a mental map of the classes to which they pertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine this, you can use the [`superclasses`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/superclasses.html) function:

```
superclasses('LinearModel')
superclasses('GeneralizedLinearMixedModel')
```

This will return the names of the *visible* superclasses for each case. As you'll see, both inherit from the [abstract](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/abstract-classes-and-interfaces.html) superclass `classreg.regr.ParametricRegression`.

You can also view the actual [`classdef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/classdef.html) files and look at the [inheritances](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html). In your Command Window, type `edit LinearModel` and `edit  GeneralizedLinearMixedModel`. You will see, respectively:

```
classdef (Sealed = true) LinearModel < classreg.regr.TermsRegression
```

and

```
classdef (Sealed = true) GeneralizedLinearMixedModel < classreg.regr.LinearLikeMixedModel
```

And so on. Both `LinearModel` and `GeneralizedLinearMixedModel` are [`Sealed`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/control-allowed-subclasses.html#bs_pobw), meaning they are not allowed to be subclassed.

**Why does `coefTest` "accept" objects both `LinearModel` and `GeneralizedLinearMixedModel` class objects?**

Both `LinearModel` and `GeneralizedLinearMixedModel` have methods called `coefTest`: [`LinearModel/coefTest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.coeftest.html) and [`GeneralizedLinearMixedModel/coefTest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmixedmodel.coeftest.html). Despite the name, these are entirely separate functions. Which method gets called is determined by the class of the object you pass to it. The methods of each of these classes are listed in their respective documentation, however, you can also use the [`methods`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html) function on an object of either class to list its public methods.

Comment: This is very educational.  However,  was wondering if this means that the actual class of the coefTest argument should be specified as ParametricRegression rather than GeneralizedLinearMixedModel?  After all, it seems to accept both LinearModel and GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, and ParametricRegression is whre their ancestor paths merge.  Unless there are automatic conversion (that would also explain it).

Comment: @user36800: I don't see a reason why you'd want/need to do that. At least in R2015a [`coefTest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.coeftest.html) is a method of the `LinearModel` class. `coefTest` may accept other inputs (i.e, doesn't perform full validation), but the R2015a documentation suggests using `fitlm` or `stepwiselm`. Both of these return `LinearModel` objects.

Comment: Just looking to understand why a function that accepts a LinearModel argument will also accept a GeneralizedLinearMixedModel object. From my understanding of object-oriented, functions that accept an object of a certain class will also accept objects of a derived class, which is why it seems odd that coefTest wasn't documented as accepting a ParametricRegression object.  It's the only way I know of which makes this possible, other than an automatic conversion from GeneralizedLinearMixedModel to LinearModel. Different languages have different ways to arrange such automatic conversions.

Comment: In case I obfuscated the remaining point of confusion in that last comment, would anyone be able to explain why coefTest accepts an object of class GeneralizedLineraMixedModel?  According to the help, coefTest accepts a LinearModel object, which is not a parent (or ancestor) of GeneralizedLinearMixedModel.

Comment: Thanks.  I got burned again by overloading.  Have to keep an eye out for that in the future.